# How to find the polynomial which has the sum of two cube roots as one of its roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

For example. How do I find the polynomial which has $\sqrt[3]2 + \sqrt[3]3$ as one of its roots?

( Hint: polynomial is $x^9-15x^6-87x^3-125$ )

Comment: Of course, thanks. I modified the title to avoid further confusion.

Comment: You need to specify what coefficients are allowed. If there are no restrictions, you can take $x-\sqrt[3]2 - \sqrt[3]3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$A=\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]2\implies A^3=3+2+3\sqrt[3]6(A)\implies A^3-5=3A\sqrt[3]6$$

Now cube both sides

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a whole bunch of terms and powers?

Comment: @Prometheus, $$A=3+2+3\sqrt[3]6(\sqrt[3]3+\sqrt[3]2)=5+3\sqrt[3]6A$$, right?

Comment: I have (A-5)^3 = ... etc. But, I got the idea.

Comment: @ndroock1, That's was I meant

Comment: $A-3A\sqrt[3]{6}=5,A(1-3\sqrt[3]{6})=5,A=\frac{5}{1-3\sqrt[3]{6}}$ Or am I missing something?

Comment: @kingW3, Please find the edited  version

Comment: Edited version is still not correct. See my previous comment.

Comment: @ndroock1, Please pinpoint the mistake

Comment: @ndroock1, Have you noticed "Now cube both sides"?

Comment: You are right, it's OK.  I added the final poly as a hint to the question.